# Error en PHP variable indefinida

Tags: php

Que tal buenos días, tengo el siguiente codigo en PHP:

```
    <div class="wrap">
        <form id="ContactForm" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">

                <label>Asunto:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="asunto" name="asunto" placeholder="Asunto:" value="<?php if(!$enviado && isset($asunto)) echo $asunto ?>">

                <label>E-mail:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail:" value="<?php if(!$enviado && isset($email)) echo $email ?>">

                <label>Mensaje:</label>
                <textarea name="mensaje" class="form_control" id="mensaje" placeholder="Escribe aqui tu mensaje"></textarea>
  <?php if(!empty($errores)): ?>
  <div class="alert error">
    <?php echo $errores; ?>
  </div>  
<?php elseif ($enviado): ?>
  <div class="alert exito">
    <p>Enviado Correctamente</p>
  </div>  
<?php endif ?>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn_primary" value="Enviar Correo"></input>
        </form>
```

En la parte de la programación tengo lo siguiente:

```
    <?php 

$errores='';
$enviado='';
$mensaje_enviar='';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $asunto=$_POST['asunto'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $mensaje=$_POST['mensaje'];

    if (!empty($asunto)) {
        $asunto=trim($asunto);
        $asunto=filter_var($asunto, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }else{
        $errores='Por favor ingresa un nombre <br />';
    }
    if (!empty($email)) {
        $email=filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $errores .='Por favor ingresa un correo valido <br />';
        }
    }else{
        $errores .='Por favor ingresa un correo <br />';
    }

    if (!empty($mensaje)) {
        $mensaje=htmlspecialchars($mensaje);
        $mensaje=trim($mensaje);
        $mensaje=stripcslashes($mensaje);
    }else{
        $errores .='Por favor ingresa el mensaje <br />';
    }

    if (!$errores) {
        $destinatario='micorreo@gmail.com';
        $asunto='Correo enviado desde';
        $mensaje_enviar="Asunto:" .$asunto;
        $mensaje_enviar.="E-mail:" .$email;
        $mensaje_enviar.="Mensaje:" . $mensaje;

        mail($destinatario, $asunto, $mensaje_enviar);
        $enviado=true;

    }
}

require 'Contacto.view.php';

 ?>
```

Y me lanza el siguiente error que adjuntare en una imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Podrían ayudarme con este código? La variable en donde me marca el error ya está definida.

Comment: Tal vez probar con isset() cuando verificas la existencia de la variable o de un valor?

Comment: No se ve tu imagen, es contacto.view.php linea 82?

Comment: Exacto, la linea 82 es la siguiente: <?php elseif ($enviado): ?>

Comment: @GuillermoRicardoSpindolaBri el formulario lo muestras por delante del código php?

Comment: Puedes intentar agregando a las variables que tienes en el form un @ antes de $ ejemplo: @$enviado

Answer (score 2):

### Pruebalo te funcionara tu mismo veras el error

Este es el index.php ahora pruebalo amigo. Saludos!!!

```
<?php 

$errores='';
$enviado='';
$mensaje_enviar='';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $asunto=$_POST['asunto'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $mensaje=$_POST['mensaje'];

    if (!empty($asunto)) {
        $asunto=trim($asunto);
        $asunto=filter_var($asunto, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }else{
        $errores='Por favor ingresa un nombre <br />';
    }
    if (!empty($email)) {
        $email=filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $errores .='Por favor ingresa un correo valido <br />';
        }
    }else{
        $errores .='Por favor ingresa un correo <br />';
    }

    if (!empty($mensaje)) {
        $mensaje=htmlspecialchars($mensaje);
        $mensaje=trim($mensaje);
        $mensaje=stripcslashes($mensaje);
    }else{
        $errores .='Por favor ingresa el mensaje <br />';
    }

    if (!$errores) {
        $destinatario='micorreo@gmail.com';
        $asunto='Correo enviado desde';
        $mensaje_enviar="Asunto:" .$asunto;
        $mensaje_enviar.="E-mail:" .$email;
        $mensaje_enviar.="Mensaje:" . $mensaje;

        mail($destinatario, $asunto, $mensaje_enviar);
        $enviado=true;

    }
}

require 'contacto.view.php';

 ?>
```

Este es el contacto.view.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
        <form id="ContactForm" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">

                <label>Asunto:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="asunto" name="asunto" placeholder="Asunto:" value="<?php if(!$enviado && isset($asunto)) echo $asunto ?>">

                <label>E-mail:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail:" value="<?php if(!$enviado && isset($email)) echo $email ?>">

                <label>Mensaje:</label>
                <textarea name="mensaje" class="form_control" id="mensaje" placeholder="Escribe aqui tu mensaje"></textarea>
  <?php if(!empty($errores)): ?>
  <div class="alert error">
    <?php echo $errores; ?>
  </div>  
<?php elseif ($enviado): ?>
  <div class="alert exito">
    <p>Enviado Correctamente</p>
  </div>  
<?php endif ?>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn_primary" value="Enviar Correo"></input>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

la variable $enviado no esta definida

Comment: Como es eso, si la estoy definiendo

Comment: Pues en el código que pusiste no se ve definida. Bueno es en el archivo donde hay html, en el otro si esta, pero el error es en el otro archivo. Solo la usas pero no la definiste.

Comment: Aqui esta definida <?php 

$errores='';
$enviado='';
$mensaje_enviar='';

Comment: Si pero ese código es de otro archivo, no del archivo donde marca el error.

Answer (score 0):

la variable $enviado, la tienes iniciada como una cadena de texto y luego la estas tratando como un capo booleano, esa puede ser una de las causas del error. Prueba iniciandola asi $enviado=false;

Comment: Para PHP **false** === ' ' o igual a 0. Entonces es válida esa parte del codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada, una pregunta. El codigo **PHP** está antes o después del **HTML**?

---

Si está despues del **HTML**, esa es la razón por la cual no está captando la variable **$enviado**. Siendo asi que:

La variable **$enviado** no está declarada. La condicion que ejecutas en los campos del formulario están comprovando si **$enviado === true** o **$enviado === false**, pero no evalua su existencia, como lo hace la funcion **isset**. Entonces, al no "encontrarse" dicha variable, lanza un **notice**.

La solucion que te recomendaría, es que para las variables que sepas que aun no estan declaradas o cargadas las llames de la siguiente forma:

**@$variable**

Y así PHP no lanzará ningun error en caso de no encontrar la variable, luego cuando se envia el formulario, el codigo ya se lee y las variables toman sus respectivos valores y ahora la variable si se toma en cuenta :)